# Yesod database migration loop

Tags: haskell, database-migration, yesod

I am running Yesod and accessing a MySQL database.

My model is:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
Email
    email Text
    userId UserId Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe
    UniqueEmail email
Comment json -- Adding "json" causes ToJSON and FromJSON instances to be derived.
    message Text
    userId UserId Maybe
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show

 -- By default this file is used in Model.hs (which is imported by Foundation.hs)
```

When I run the Yesod application, it repeats the following:

```
Starting devel application
Migrating: ALTER TABLE `user` ALTER COLUMN `password` DROP DEFAULT
28/Mar/2017:23:46:44 +0200 [Debug#SQL] ALTER TABLE `user` ALTER COLUMN `password` DROP DEFAULT; []
devel.hs: ConnectionError {errFunction = "query", errNumber = 1101, errMessage = "BLOB/TEXT column 'password' can't have a default value"}
Unexpected: child process exited with ExitFailure 1
Trying again
Starting devel application
Migrating: ALTER TABLE `user` ALTER COLUMN `password` DROP DEFAULT
28/Mar/2017:23:46:46 +0200 [Debug#SQL] ALTER TABLE `user` ALTER COLUMN `password` DROP DEFAULT; []
devel.hs: ConnectionError {errFunction = "query", errNumber = 1101, errMessage = "BLOB/TEXT column 'password' can't have a default value"}
Unexpected: child process exited with ExitFailure 1
Trying again
```

It goes in a never ending loop.

A workaround is commenting the following line from `Application.hs` which means disabling database migration:

```
runLoggingT (runSqlPool (runMigration migrateAll) pool) logFunc
```

But if I use the workaround, I get another error:

```
28/Mar/2017:23:56:28 +0200 [Error#yesod-core] Foundation.hs:(137,5)-(144,45): Non-exhaustive patterns in function isAuthorized
 @(yesod-core-1.4.32-6HthMZNCl0sEMRz6GJ4QO1:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:693:5)
28/Mar/2017:23:56:28 +0200 [Debug#SQL] SELECT `ident`,`password` FROM `user` WHERE `id`=? ; [PersistInt64 1]
GET /test
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error 0.006514s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `default=NULL` to each `Text Maybe` column fixes this problem. In some MySQL versions you also need to change the column type by adding `sqltype=varchar(255)`. In your case the model should look like this:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe sqltype=varchar(255) default=NULL
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
Email
    email Text
    userId UserId Maybe
    verkey Text Maybe sqltype=varchar(255) default=NULL
    UniqueEmail email
Comment json -- Adding "json" causes ToJSON and FromJSON instances to be derived.
    message Text
    userId UserId Maybe
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show

 -- By default this file is used in Model.hs (which is imported by Foundation.hs)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [this bug](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/563) related to migration and default values.

You can try [this workaround](https://gistpages.com/posts/blob_text_column_can_t_have_a_default_value_create_table_from_mysql) to change the behaviour of MySQL In default values or maybe try changing the type of the column from `text` to `varchar`?

Comment: Thank you! Solved it using: `alter table user modify column password varchar(255) default ' ';`